# How does Crusader Kings 2 calculate levy percentages?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I'm trying to decipher CK2, and how I can amass an army.  One of my vassals has a town, and in this town are 132/158 levy troops, and it says I can raise the top 20.8% of the levy.  At the top, it says "we can currently raise 6 soldiers".  How is 20.8% of 132 = 6?  What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade, and thanks for your first question here. If you have figured it out yourself (and can corroborate it with other examples), it's totally okay to answer your own question! This will allow you to amass reputation and start becoming a more contributing member of Arqade. :)

Answer (score 2):

*(copied From Nick's question)*

I figured it out:

20.8% of the total 158 is 32. You can only take the top troops off the levy, meaning since there are 26 troops missing (158-132), I can only take 6 (32-26) troops.